# Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag img exception in Itextsharp xmlworker

Tags: xhtml, itext

I am trying to convert the whole webpage into pdf using itextsharp 5.5.10.0 but it gives me 'Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag img' error

following is the source code of webpage which I am trying to convert

```
 <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse:collapse" cellpadding="4" 
 border="1">



<tr>
    <td   colspan="3" style="height: 25px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 
 12px">
    <div >1. Personal Details  </div>
    </td>

 </tr>

<tr>
    <td  colspan="2" style="font-size: 10px; height: 3%;width:65%"><span 
 style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 10px"> Name*  </span>(Same as ID 
 proof): <asp:Label ID="lbName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>

     <td  rowspan="4" style="width:35%"   >
         <div>

    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/118/118781.png" 
  height="100" alt="" width="100" id="imgs" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </td>


  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td style="height: 3%;font-size: 10px" colspan="2" >
  <div><span style="font-weight:bold" > Maiden name </span>(If any)* : 
  <asp:Label ID="lbMaidenName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></div> 
  </td>


  </tr>

 <tr>
 <td style="height: 3%;font-size: 10px" colspan="2"><div><span 
 style="font-weight:bold"> Father's/Spouse Name* </span>: <asp:Label 
 ID="lbFatherName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></div></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td style="height: 3%;font-size: 10px" colspan="2"><div><span 
 style="font-weight:bold"> Mother name*</span> : <asp:Label 
 ID="lbMotherName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></div></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

I tried everything ,

```
ex-<img src='...'/>, <img src='...'/> and  <img src='...'></img> and <img 
src='...'><img>
```

but all this image tags gives me same error,Please help me  to resolve this issue 
I even tried to validate this html but on image tag it shows warning like this

NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES

Comment: Do you need the div tag as a parent to the img tag?

Comment: Not really...But It gives me the same error when It is in <td> tag anyway....I even tried putting img tag outside the table...But same error again

Comment: Just to clarify, are you sending this exact code to iTextSharp, or the generated HTML? If the latter, are you sure that asp.net doesn't do nasty things like remove the slash? Oh, and do you need the runat attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and plopped it in to an XML file and loaded that file in the Gecko rendering engine (Waterfox / Firefox).

After using HTML comments to hide the ASP code the XML (your HTML) rendered correctly.

I program with PHP, not ASP though I *can* tell you that you'll need to comment out your ASP code and render it using an XML parser instead of HTML parser (serve as `application/xhtml+xml`). Each time you uncomment the relevant ASP code either the page will still render or it will break. It might only break for one set of ASP code, it might for all of them. Whatever ASP bits of code are breaking your page you will need to look up the relevant documentation.

It is my understanding that ASP outputs actual HTML code unlike PHP (if so this is very bad as it is a loss of total control of what is sent to the client). If true you will have to work in a more fine-grained approach and only output XML compliant code yourself directly based on what data you're working with in ASP.